# Why is creating a masked numpy array so slow with mask=None or mask=0

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Today I profiled a function and I found a (at least to me) weird bottleneck: Creating a masked array with `mask=None` or `mask=0` to initialize a mask with all zeros but the same shape as the `data` is very slow:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.ones((100, 100, 100))

>>> %timeit ma_array = np.ma.array(data, mask=None, copy=False)
1 loop, best of 3: 803 ms per loop

>>> %timeit ma_array = np.ma.array(data, mask=0, copy=False)
1 loop, best of 3: 807 ms per loop
```

on the other hand using `mask=False` or creating the mask by hand is much faster:

```
>>> %timeit ma_array = np.ma.array(data, mask=False, copy=False)
1000 loops, best of 3: 438 µs per loop

>>> %timeit ma_array = np.ma.array(data, mask=np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=bool), copy=False)
1000 loops, best of 3: 453 µs per loop
```

Why is giving `None` or `0` almost 2000 times slower than `False` or `np.zeros(data.shape)` as `mask` parameter? Given that the [function docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.array.html) only says that it:

> Must be convertible to an array of booleans with the same shape as data. True indicates a masked (i.e. invalid) data.

I use python 3.5, numpy 1.11.0 on Windows 10

Comment: Have you dug into the numpy code yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mask=False` is special-cased in the [NumPy 1.11.0 source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/ma/core.py#L2776):

```
if mask is True and mdtype == MaskType:
    mask = np.ones(_data.shape, dtype=mdtype)
elif mask is False and mdtype == MaskType:
    mask = np.zeros(_data.shape, dtype=mdtype)
```

`mask=0` or `mask=None` take the slow path, making a 0-dimensional mask array and going through `np.resize` to resize it.

Comment: And `resize` does `a = concatenate((a,)*n_copies)`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe @user2357112 has the explanation. I profiled both cases, here are the results:

```
In [14]: q.run('q.np.ma.array(q.data, mask=None, copy=False)')
         49 function calls in 0.161 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(array)
        1    0.154    0.154    0.154    0.154 :0(concatenate)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.161    0.161 :0(exec)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(getattr)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(hasattr)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isinstance)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(len)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(ravel)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(reduce)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(reshape)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(update)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.161    0.161 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.161    0.161 core.py:2704(__new__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:2838(_update_from)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:2864(__array_finalize__)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:3264(__setattr__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.161    0.161 core.py:6119(array)
        1    0.007    0.007    0.161    0.161 fromnumeric.py:1097(resize)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:128(reshape)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1383(ravel)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:484(asanyarray)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.161    0.161 profile:0(q.np.ma.array(q.data, mask=None, copy=False))

In [15]: q.run('q.np.ma.array(q.data, mask=False, copy=False)')
         37 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(array)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(exec)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(getattr)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(hasattr)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(isinstance)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(update)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(zeros)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:2704(__new__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:2838(_update_from)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:2864(__array_finalize__)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:3264(__setattr__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 core.py:6119(array)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 profile:0(q.np.ma.array(q.data, mask=False, copy=False))
```

So it seems that the concatenation step of arrays is the bottleneck.